# construct parameters of a script based on dynamic values of variables

Tags: bash, array

Team, I have a set of parameters that are defined inside this script-A with their default values as "DEFAULT". When users set these parameters which are variables to any value other than "DEFAULT", then I have to run another script with updated variable values else i run that another script-B with default values. So, i have three cases

I am simulating jenkins setting of parameters inside script. DEFAULT value is preset on jenkins job that are set as environment variables then this script is run.
So, user if he does not change any parameters and let the value of all fio_gen as DEFAULT, then they are replaced by ones I have defined in script.

```
1-Run Script-B with DEFAULT variable values
2-Run Script-B with all-non-DEFAULT variable values
3-Run Script-B with mixed variable values.. some default and some non.
```

My Code is below which is identifying which variables are default and not default but I cannot think of logic to do case-3 for mixed above.

Shall I use associate arrays in vars_ioengine_defaults and compare and use? or what is good approach?

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -a vars=(IOEngine TestType Threads BlockSize FileSize DatasetSize QueueDepth RunTime UDCName)
for var_name in "${vars[@]}"
do
 if [ -z "${!var_name}" ]; then
   echo "Missing environment variable $var_name"
   exit 1
 fi
done

#***Comment unComment to test 3 cases"
#DatasetSize="DEFAULT"
#BlockSize="DEFAULT"
#DatasetSize="nonDEFAULT"
#BlockSize="nonDEFAULT"
DatasetSize="DEFAULT"
BlockSize="NON-DEFAULT"


preset="DEFAULT"
declare -a dynamic_vars=( DatasetSize BlockSize )

number_of_dynamic_vars="${#dynamic_vars[@]}"
number_of_default_values=0

overwrite_all() {
        printf "all non-defaults variables\n"
    fio_gen
}
overwrite_some() {
        printf "some defaults variables\n"
    for [[ "${!var}" == "$preset" ]]
    do
     # SOME LOGIC HERE TO replace non-default and call this function
    fio_gen
    done
}
overwrite_none() {
        printf " all defaults variables\n"
    vars_ioengine_defaults
    fio_gen
}


check_vars() {
for var in "${dynamic_vars[@]}"
do
  [[ "${!var}" == "$preset" ]] && ((number_of_default_values++))
done

if [[ "$number_of_default_values" -eq 0 ]]; then
  echo "None var is default"
  overwrite_all
elif [[ "$number_of_default_values" -eq "$number_of_dynamic_vars" ]]; then
  echo "All defaults"
  overwrite_none
else
  echo "Mixed"
  overwrite_some
  echo $var
fi
}

vars_ioengine_defaults() {
  RunTime="0"
  UDCNAme="stage"
if [[ "$IOEnginge" == "psync" ]]  && [[ "$TestType" == "read" ]]; then
  QueueDepth="0"
  DatasetSize="3G"
  BlockSize="2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256,512,1024"
  Threads="1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256"
  FileSize="3M"
elif [[ "$IOEngine" == "psync" ]]  && [[ "$TestType" == "randread" ]]; then
  QueueDepth="0"
  DatasetSize="1G"
  BlockSize="8,16,32"
  Threads="16,32,64,128,256"
  FileSize="32k"
elif [[ "$IOEngine" == "libaio" ]]  && [[ "$TestType" == "read" ]]; then
  QueueDepth="16"
  DatasetSize="3G"
  BlockSize="2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256,512,1024"
  Threads="1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256"
  FileSize="3M"
elif [[ "$IOEngine" == "libaio" ]]  && [[ "$TestType" == "randread" ]]; then
  QueueDepth="16"
  DatasetSize="1G"
  BlockSize="8,16,32"
  Threads="16,32,64,128,256"
  FileSize="32k"
fi
}

fio_gen() {
    echo "iteratre on -p $IOEngine -t $TestType -j $Threads -b $BlockSize -s $FileSize -d $DatasetSize -q $QueueDepth -r $RunTime -u $UDCName"
}
check_vars
```

Comment: (Maybe I should have asked this one question ago…). Is there a reason you need to tell these three cases *apart*? and treat them *differently*? A straightforward approach is to check each relevant variable *separately* and fall back to its default value if needed. Do you really need to use `DEFAULT` as the special value to be replaced? How about "unset or null"? In this case the syntax suggested in harrymc's answer will be most useful: `DatasetSize="${DatasetSize:-default value}"`. Do this to every variable that needs a default value and you're set.

Comment: Basically, its a jenkins user who can set parameters as DEFAULT or non-default. so which ever parameter is not DEFAULT, then i need to use that in calling fio_gen

Comment: I don't know Jenkins. I guess you're saying "unset or null" is not an option and you need a solution for `DEFAULT`, albeit it may not be as elegant as `DatasetSize="${DatasetSize:-default value}"`. Please confirm.

Comment: DEFAULT is just a string that am setting in default parameter value to all the variables. I can have this to anything but it should be meaning full to user. looking at "DEFAULT" user knows what the values will be as they are statically predefined inside script. also the call fio_gen with parameters can be in any order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a stub of a solution that implements the following procedure:

1. Source the config file where all the default values are defined in variables named with `DFLT_` prefix. E.g. `DFLT_BlockSize` defines the default value for `BlockSize`.
2. For every default-variable (i.e. variable with name starting with `DFLT_`) …

   1. obtain the name of the actual variable;
   2. if the value under the actual variable is `DEFAULT`, replace it with the value of default-variable.

Let it be our `config.defaults`:

```
DFLT_BlockSize=5
DFLT_DatasetSize="1 2 3 infinity"
```

And this is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

preset="DEFAULT"

#***Comment unComment to test 3 cases"
#DatasetSize="DEFAULT"
#BlockSize="DEFAULT"
#DatasetSize="nonDEFAULT"
#BlockSize="nonDEFAULT"
DatasetSize="DEFAULT"
BlockSize="NON-DEFAULT"

substitute_defaults() {
  local dvar var
  . "/path/to/config.defaults"   # use the actual path to the config
  for dvar in "${!DFLT_@}"; do
    var="${dvar#DFLT_}"
    declare -n var
    [[ "$var" == "$preset" ]] && var="${!dvar}"
    declare +n var
  done
}

substitute_defaults

echo "$BlockSize"
echo "$DatasetSize"
```

Explanation:

- `"${!DFLT_@}"` returns names of all variables that start with `DFLT_`. In each iteration of `for` loop `$dvar` expands to the next such name, e.g. `DFLT_BlockSize`.
- `"${dvar#DFLT_}"` is `"$dvar"` with leading `DFLT_` removed. E.g. if `$dvar` expands to `DFLT_BlockSize` then `${dvar#DFLT_}` expands to `BlockSize`. This is stored as `var`.
- `declare -n var` makes all references, assignments, and attribute modifications to `var` (except those using or changing the `-n` attribute itself) be performed on the variable referenced by the value of `var`. In our example (where `$var` used to expand to `BlockSize`) from now on `$var` behaves like `$BlockSize` and `var=` behaves like `BlockSize=`.
- `${!dvar}` is something similar that works without `declare -n`: if `$dvar` expands to `DFLT_BlockSize` then `${!dvar}` behaves like `$DFLT_BlockSize`. (If we did `declare -n dvar`, we would need just `$dvar` to get the same effect).
- So when `$dvar` expands to `DFLT_BlockSize`, the line

  ```
  [[ "$var" == "$preset" ]] && var="${!dvar}"
  ```

  behaves like

  ```
  [[ "$BlockSize" == "$preset" ]] && BlockSize="$DFLT_BlockSize"
  ```
- We need `declare +n var` (`+n` revokes `-n`) so `var="${dvar#DFLT_}"` in the next loop changes `var`, not `BlockSize`.

Notes:

- I used a distinct file for config just to separate settings from code. You can define these `DFLT_` variables directly in your script (instead of `. "/path/to/config.defaults"`).
- Since `config.defaults` is sourced, you should treat it as a part of the script. In particular it's by no means limited to setting variables; any code you put in this file will be executed as if it was in the script itself. But this also means you can put comments in the config file; or conditional statements! (And just in case: `foo=bar rm -rf /precious/data` will run `rm`! `foo="bar rm -rf /precious/data"` won't).
- You may want to keep the default-variables local to the function. In such case entries in the config file should be like `local DFLT_foo=bar`. I decided to keep the example file simple, yet `local` seems reasonable.
- My script doesn't care where default-variables come from or what actual variables (or positional parameters!) they refer to. Trying to use `DFLT_1` to affect `$1` will lead to errors because positional parameters behave somewhat differently than regular variables.

Comment: Thank you. I want to avoid having config file and deal with script alone. So, with that said, how should i define my variables inside script? should they be like an associative array?

Comment: @fmaabd In the same way I did in the config file. My answer already says "You can define these `DFLT_` variables directly in your script (instead of `. "/path/to/config.defaults"`)."

Comment: @fmaabd I think you could do something similar with an associative array but here I chose slightly different approach.

Comment: okay in layman terms:  like below ?
local dvar var
  .   $DFLT_BlockSize $DFLT_DatasetSize $DFLT_RunTime $DFLT_Threads ...etc

Comment: @fmaabd Please research what sourcing is. In layman terms you should define `DFLT_BlockSize="whatever you want"` and similar variables. It doesn't matter if it's in the script, in a sourced file, in the environment – as long as the function sees the variables.

Comment: I tested all the three cases: your algo works like a charm. thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is supplying default parameters to a bash script,
then this is answered by posts on our sister site Stack Overflow.

If the parameters are positional, you will find several solutions in the post
[How to write a bash script that takes optional input arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9332802/how-to-write-a-bash-script-that-takes-optional-input-arguments).

These solutions use parameter expansion as defined in the
[Bash Reference Manual - 3.5.3 Shell Parameter Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion),
and especially elements like `${1:-foo}`.

For example, you could have in the script:

```
ARG1=${1:-foo}
ARG2=${2:-bar}
ARG3=${4:-$(date)}
```

The above script would require the missing parameters to always be the last ones.

If you would rather use named parameters in the script, some approached are described
in the article
[Passing named arguments to shell scripts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/129391/passing-named-arguments-to-shell-scripts).

For one example from the post, if you are using single-letter
parameters such as in calling `my_script -p '/some/path' -a5`,
you could use similar code to:

```
while getopts ":a:p:" opt; do
  case $opt in
    a) arg_1="$OPTARG"
    ;;
    p) p_out="$OPTARG"
    ;;
    \?) echo "Invalid option -$OPTARG" >&2
    ;;
  esac
done
```

Comment: am unable to comprehend this solution. my need is when my parameters are set with DEFAULT, run fio_gen with them, when they are set with NON-DEFAULT, then run fio_gen with non-default, and when only some variables are set with defautl and some with non-default, then run fio_gen with those changed ones and keep remaining as is DEFAULT values which are replaced inside script.

Comment: so 1 - identify which ones are non-default then set them to non-default and set remaining to default values from script and run the fio_gen.

Comment: can you please do paste as per my script what changes are needed?